# Apply and/or in SQL query based on flags passed to stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-express, temp-tables

I need a query which can apply and/or clauses dynamically basing on the flags. I am using SQL Server 2014.

Consider the following example:

```
declare @UGFlag char(1)
declare @PGFlag char(1)
declare @DoctrateFlag  char(1)

create table #FiltQual(Candidate_ID int) -- Final Output

create table #FiltUG(Candidate_ID int)
create table #FiltPG(Candidate_ID int)
create table #FiltDOC(Candidate_ID int)

insert into #FiltUG
select '1' union
select '2' union
select '3'

insert into #FiltPG
select '1' union
select '2'

insert into #FiltPG
select '2' union
select '3' union
select '4' union
select '5' 

--Case 1
set @UGFlag='Y'
set @PGFlag='Y'
set @DoctrateFlag = 'Y'
--Desired Output 
Candidate_ID
2

Case 2 
set @UGFlag='N'
set @PGFlag='N'
set @DoctrateFlag = 'N'
Desired Output 
Candidate_ID
1
2
3
4
5

Case 3: 
set @UGFlag='N'
set @PGFlag='Y'
set @DoctrateFlag = 'N'
Desired Output 
Candidate_ID
1
2

Case 4:
set @UGFlag='Y'
set @PGFlag='Y'
set @DoctrateFlag = 'N'
Desired Output 
Candidate_ID
1
2
```

I want to populate data into `#FiltQual` basing on the trhee flags. Flags can contain either 'Y' or 'N', if it is 'Y' then 'And' should be apllied else 'or' should be applied.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That code is product specific.)

Comment: SQL Server 2014 Express Edition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
SELECT COALESCE(UG.Candidate_ID, PG.Candidate_ID, DOC.Candidate_ID) AS Candidate_ID
FROM #FiltUG AS UG
FULL OUTER JOIN #FiltPG AS PG ON UG.Candidate_ID = PG.Candidate_ID
FULL OUTER JOIN #FiltDOC AS DOC ON PG.Candidate_ID = DOC.Candidate_ID
WHERE ((@UGFlag='Y' AND UG.Candidate_ID IS NOT NULL) OR (@UGFlag='N'))
      AND
      ((@PGFlag='Y' AND PG.Candidate_ID IS NOT NULL) OR (@PGFlag='N'))
      AND
      ((@DoctrateFlag='Y' AND DOC.Candidate_ID IS NOT NULL) OR (@DoctrateFlag='N'))
```

The key idea is to use a `FULL JOIN` between all tables. Then using, for example:

```
(@UGFlag='Y' AND UG.Candidate_ID IS NOT NULL) OR (@UGFlag='N')
```

we apply the `NOT NULL` condition to a table (`#FiltUG`) if the corresponding table filter (`@UGFlag`) is equal to `'Y`.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9f026/1)

Answer (score 0):

Not a complete answer, but the following abstract pattern can work.  What you do is stack a check for the condition indicator in with the actual check.

```
SELECT *
FROM Table
WHERE (@ConditionIndicator = 'Y' AND (Column = @Value))
```

A slightly more concrete example, that does not address your sample data:

```
DECLARE @Filter NCHAR(1);
SET @Filter = 'Y'; -- Change to 'N' (or anything other than 'Y') to see the results change

SELECT *
FROM sysobjects
WHERE (@Filter = 'Y' AND name = 'sysrscols')
```

When @Filter == 'Y', it returns 1 row.  When @Filter is anything other than 'Y', it returns no rows.

Hope this helps.

Edited to add:

Sorry, just re-read your question.  You need something more like the below, but it effectively uses the same pattern:

```
DECLARE @Filter NCHAR(1);
SET @Filter = 'Y';

SELECT *
FROM sysobjects
WHERE (@Filter = 'Y' AND (name = 'sysrscols' AND xtype = 'S'))
    OR (@Filter != 'Y' AND (name = 'sysrscols' OR xtype = 'S'))
```